# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'EVP_MD_CTX_new'

Tags: python, google-api-client, pyopenssl

I'm attempting to use the Python package `googleapiclient` to download analytics, but it's giving me an OpenSSL related traceback:

```
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleanalytics/auth/__init__.py", line 95, in authenticate
    accounts = oauth.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleanalytics/auth/credentials.py", line 216, in normalized_fn
    return fn(credentials)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleanalytics/auth/oauth.py", line 44, in authenticate
    raw_accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()['items']
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 931, in execute
    headers=self.headers,
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 190, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 572, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 842, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 869, in _do_refresh_request
    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1549, in _generate_refresh_request_body
    assertion = self._generate_assertion()
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1677, in _generate_assertion
    private_key, self.private_key_password), payload)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 92, in make_signed_jwt
    signature = signer.sign(signing_input)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_openssl_crypt.py", line 99, in sign
    return crypto.sign(self._key, message, 'sha256')
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3008, in sign
    md_ctx = _lib.EVP_MD_CTX_new()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'EVP_MD_CTX_new'
```

I'm using versions:

```
google-api-python-client==2.26.1
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
```

I'm guessing the cause of the error is a version mismatch between the Python package and system library, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. How do I diagnose this issue?

Comment: You can verify the underlying used openssl library version (and more) with 
`python3 -m OpenSSL.debug`.

Then verify the supported version listed in the documentation: https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/install.html#supported-openssl-versions

Comment: Was there an answer to this in the end? I'm running into the same issue at the moment.

Comment: @RobTheRobot16 I think I had an out of date child package. I deleted my virtualenv and reinstall from my pip requirements.txt, and that fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to dependency mismatch between pyopenssl and cyrptography.
I managed to solve this issue by downgrading cryptography library using following command.

> pip install cryptography==36.0.0